# IntSlider callback function? Editor Scripting

Tags: unity-game-engine, slider, editor

I just got into Editor Scripting recently and I'm still getting a hold of all the basics. I wanted to know if the IntSlider (that we use to create a slider of integer values) has any methods or functions that can be used to get more functionality?

Something like the Slider class:
You have -maxValue, -minValue, -value, -onValueChanged (Callback executed when the value of the slider is changed)

These work during the "Play" mode.

I need to access this information while in the editor. **Specifically: I need to access the onValueChanged (if it exists) of the IntSlider so I can assign a function for it to execute.**

IntSlider Code:

`totalRooms = EditorGUILayout.IntSlider(new GUIContent ("Total Rooms"), totalRooms, 0, 10);`

Is there a way to achieve this for the inspector? Or something that can be created to solve this? If you can point me in the right direction, I'd be grateful.

[image]

I'm using Unity 5.3.1f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such event in Unity at the moment. However this can be implemented easily like this:

Add a `UnityEvent` in your actual script.

```
public UnityEvent OnVariablesValueChanged;
```

Then in your editor script check if value is changed. (Note: I tried to write easily understandable code sample for this. you can change it accordingly)

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MyScript))]
public class MyScriptEditor : Editor 
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        MyScript myTarget = (MyScript)target;
        int prevValue = myTarget.variable;
        myTarget.variable = EditorGUI.IntSlider(new Rect(0,0,100, 20), prevValue, 1, 10);
        int newValue = myTarget.variable;
        if (prevValue != newValue)
        {
            Debug.Log("New value of variable is  :" + myTarget.variable);
            myTarget.OnVariablesValueChanged.Invoke();
        }
        base.OnInspectorGUI();
    }
}
```

Then add listener to `OnVariablesValueChanged` event from inspector.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I implemented this and it works! I love this solution.